# How can I center component with Flexbox with "fixed width"

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I´m making my component with the next code (App.component, the highest parent):

**app.component.html**

```
    <div class="wrapper_flex">
  <div style="width:400px; background-color: pink;"></div>
  <div style="flex: 0 0 600px;">
    <app-feed></app-feed>
  </div>
  <div style="width:300px; background-color: green;"></div>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
.wrapper_flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

This is my "app-feed":

**feed.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <h4>Inicio</h4>
    <div>
        <app-tweet [division]="true" [tweet]=tweet [retweets]="retweets" [likes]="likes" *ngFor="let tweet of tweets"></app-tweet>
    </div>
</div>
```

**feed.component.css**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: red;
}

.header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 16px 16px 16px;
}
```

But when I refresh the page, the container moves a little.
How can I can make my component "Feed" stays in the center of my flexbox without moving, stay fixed (with a fixed width)

Live demo:
https://gifyu.com/image/Sw9fN

Buf if i remove the "h4" tag in **feed.component.html**, the container not moves, as i want to expect from the another approach.

Expected result (with h1 tag):
https://gifyu.com/image/Sw9fK

I´m using Angular 11

Comment: Why you apply `display: flex` to `.container` class?

Comment: Because, i want to display another component above h1 tag, but i removed to explain more easy. Actually its a component to make a Tweet, to give you and idea.

Comment: But with `display: flex` you are telling to put those elements next to each other, not one above the other. Is that what you want?

Comment: Ok, yep, actually I added  flex-direction: column, to make it vertical, but the same result, moves a little at the beginning

Comment: Yeah, that's the right approach when you want to align the elements vertically, but the natural behavior of those elements inside `.container` class is render one above the other since are block elements, so I don't see the need of `flex` if you are not applying an `align-items` property.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Actually, with this approach, I remove all `.container` attributes, and only leave `width: 100%`, but the same results. 
The `div` wrapper of "app-tweet" have  `display: flex; `  and  `flex-direction: row;`, to make the tweet container (as you can see in the demo). I dont know, if its affects the parent behavior.

Comment: That feedback that you are seeing could be due to nested flexbox.

Comment: After investigate, I solve this initial shifting adding `overflow-y: scroll` to the `html` tag

Answer (score 1):

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The initial shifting can be prevented

Found out that the problem happens when the page has no scrollbar but you expand some element and the browser shows the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

{

```
    <div class="wrapper_flex">
        <div class="right" style="width:400px; background-color: pink;"></div>
        <div style="flex: 0 0 600px;">
          <app-feed>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="h1">
                    <img style="width: 62px;
                    margin-top: 6px;
                    border-radius: 230px;" src="bg.jpg" alt="">hello
                </div>   
    <div>
        <app-tweet [division]="true" [tweet]=tweet [retweets]="retweets" [likes]="likes" *ngFor="let tweet of tweets"></app-tweet>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
        <div>hello this is Ravi</div>
    </div>

</div>
          </app-feed>
        </div>
        <div class="left" style="width: 300px; background-color: green;"></div>
      </div>
```

}
using this code you can edit your post as like in link(which is sended by you)

```
.wrapper_flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
}
.container {
    display: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```